# What is a singular space?

Tags: manifolds, singularity, orbifolds

A book I am reading on **orbifolds** uses the word singular space but doesn't say what it means. The book is Orbifolds and Stringy Topology by ALR the quote is "Orbifolds are singular spaces that are locally modelled on a quotient of a smooth manfiold by the action of a finite group".

Comment: If I could make a guess, it is a space that is smooth everywhere other than at a few localized points, called singularities.  I've seen such terminology used in physics when discussing black holes - something like a volume containing a black hole would be considered a singular space because spacetime isnt smooth at the boundaries of the black hole.  But if the book uses it only once or twice, I wouldn't worry about it... if the book repetitively uses it to gather other results, it should've defined it.

Comment: In a board sense it means something not regular/sooth. Whether or not it means something more depend on the usage.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you give context.

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: sorry it's about orbifolds, the book is *orbifolds and stringy topology* by ALR the quote is "orbifolds are singular spaces that are locally modelled on a quotient of a smooth manfiold by the action of a finite group"

Comment: You should edit this into the question.

Answer (score 3):

A manifold is locally modeled on $\Bbb R^n$. An orbifold is locally modeled on $\Bbb R^n/G$, where $G$ is a finite subgroup of $O(n)$.

On the one hand, you can think of this as allowing for singular models of manifolds. For $\Bbb Z/n \subset SO(2)$, $\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z/n$ is a cone with cone angle $2\pi/n$; or for $\Bbb Z/2 \subset O(n)$ (where the nontrivial element acts by negation on $\Bbb R^n$), the resulting object is homeomorphic to an open cone on $\Bbb{RP}^{n-1}$.

On the other hand, note that the resulting object is more structured than a topological space (or even a smooth manifold; your charts vary not just over open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, but rather that equipped with an orthogonal group action). For instance, the cone example above is topologically equivalent to $\Bbb R^2$, but not equivalent as an orbifold. So the visualization you should have of an orbifold should really look like a quotient somehow when you visualize it.

Comment: @3750 I assume you're unsatisfied with what's written here. If you don't vote up or down on, comment on, or otherwise acknowledge this answer, I can't do anything to improve it for you.

Comment: Your answer is fine, it's just that I'm trying to figure out what you're talking about because I'm not well read in this area. It would help if you gave a full definition of singular space. Also I don't quite understand your paragraph 2, can you provide more details and examples?

Comment: A singular space is not a mathematically defined object. It is a heuristic picture.